# SVN Commits and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using SVN for the first time. I was given a repo which contained several directories, one of which was a Java program directory, the others were various other things. 
I used the Eclipse SVN plugin to checkout the repo, and only checked out the relevant Java subdirectory into Eclipse (the other directories were irrelevant for my purpose).

Now I have done the changes to this directory.

Am I right in thinking that if I "commit" the updates, the new head will be created with the updated Java directory AND all the other directories? What I am worried about is losing the other directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work perfectly fine. Just ensure that your "commit" happens only in the relevant sub-directory that you have checked out via Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in thinking that if I "commit" the updates, the new head will be created with the updated Java directory AND all the other directories?

Yes, you're correct.  The other directories will still be part of HEAD.

You never "lose" anything in a version control system.  Even if you delete a directory, it will still be in the source control history.

Comment: You *can* lose things in a version control system. Ask anyone who suffered through Visual SourceSafe. But that's more loss due to data corruption than loss through normal user activities.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry. When you commit, the changes will only affect the checked out directories.